# PHP. Use geocode google API during registration step

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a user management system. During the registration process the user enters their personal information, including the address attribute.

```
    <?php
          include("database.php");
        $error = "";
          if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
              $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
              $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
              $address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
              $passwordConfirm = $_POST['passwordConfirm'];
              $privacy = $_POST['privacy'];

              //validare i valori inseriti dall'utente

              if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
              {
                $error = "Inserisci una email valida ";
              }

              else if (strlen($password < 8)) {
                $error = "La password deve contenere almeni 8 caratteri";
              }

              else if ($password != $passwordConfirm)
              {
                $error = "Le password devono coincidere!";
              }

              else {
                $error = "Ti sei appena registrato";
              }

$sql = "INSERT INTO users(username, name, surname, affiliation, department,address,position,email,web,telephone,mobile,password,privacy) VALUES('$username','$name','$surname','$affiliation','$department','$address','$position','$email','$web','$telephone','$mobile','$password','$privacy')";
              mysqli_query($database,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($database));
        header("location:index.php");
              }
        echo "$error";
        ?>
```

Thanks to 'geocode.php' I get the geographical coordinates of the address. I managed to implement a version in which the geolocation occurs after user registration. In this way (geocode.php)

```
<?php
        session_start();
        include("database.php");
        if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
          $current_user = $_SESSION['username'];
          $sql = "SELECT address FROM users WHERE username='$current_user'";
          $result = mysqli_query($database,$sql);
          $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
          }

        $address = urlencode($row['address']);
        $request_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".$address."&sensor=true";
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");
        $status = $xml->status;
        if ($status=="OK"){
            $lat = $xml->result->geometry->location->lat;
            $lng = $xml->result->geometry->location->lng;
            $latlng = "$lat,$lng";
            }
      if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
            $temp=$_SESSION['username'];
            $sql1 = "UPDATE users SET lat='$lat',lng='$lng' WHERE username='$temp'";
            mysqli_query($database,$sql1);
            }
    ?>
```

I wish I had some advice to make sure that the API call to google maps occurs during user registration.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you are looking for. 
According my understanding you want to add geo location code during registration process.

what you can do is you add following code after sanitizing address.

```
if($address !='')
{
   $address_code = urlencode($row['address']);
    $request_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".$address_code."&sensor=true";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");
    $status = $xml->status;
    if ($status=="OK"){
        $lat = $xml->result->geometry->location->lat;
        $lng = $xml->result->geometry->location->lng;
        $latlng = "$lat,$lng";
        }
   // Now you have latitude and Longitude saved in $lat and $lang respectively. You can add this in your insert query.
}
```

I hope this make sense.